# Determine the coefficients $a_n$ of the power series

Tags: real-analysis

How to determine the coefficients for the function $e^{-2x}$ (center $x_0=0$)?
First of all I determined the first 5 derivates and I got the following coefficients: $1-2x+2x^2- \frac{4}{3}x^3 +\frac{2}{3}x^4~.~.~.$ 
but I think my prof won't give me the point for those coefficients.

So if he asks for the coefficients $a_n$ do I have to determine a sum which develops those coefficients. Like $e^x = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} * x^k $

But how to "edit" this sum that it exactly develops the $a_n$ for the given $e^{-2x}$?

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$ \exp z = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}
$$
We can substitute $z = -2x$, so
$$ \exp (-2x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-2x)^j}{j!} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j 2^j}{j!} x^j
$$

Comment: So you think if my prof asks for the coefficients $a_n$ he want to see the sum for the development of the $a_n$'s? Thank you for your help!